# Using CruiseControl.net and SVN suddenly getting access to path is denied during build process

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

We're Using CruiseControl.net and SVN
We are now getting access to path is denied during build process.

There were no source changes sine the last successful build.

Any ideas what might have happened?

```
System.ArgumentException: Access to the path is denied.
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Util.IoService.DeleteIncludingReadOnlyObjects(String path)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.GetSource(IIntegrationResult result)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult result)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

Answer (score 4):

2 ideas:

1. Make sure you haven't run out of disk space room.  It'll throw "red herring errors".
2. There is an Identity (domain\user_name usually) that runs the CC.NET Service.  The "rights" of this account could be changed external from the cc.net "setup".  And cause a break to start occurring. 
   Go to Control Panel\Services..........find the CC.NET Service, find out what the Identity is......and verify that identity has permissions to "whatever".

The error above doesn't show a specific thing...thus some digging will be required.